# Texinfo: Contents and Index not showing at HTML

Tags: texinfo

I’m trying to learn Texinfo to write a book.

I started from the sample file [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Short-Sample-Texinfo-File.html#Short-Sample).

As far as I understand from [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/Contents.html) Contents is created automatically. And it works for the [PDF output](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/test/sample-doc.pdf).

But I don’t see the Contents or Index on the [HTML output](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/test/index.html).

By "Contents" I mean a page [like this](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#SEC_Contents).

Also, I’m using `makeinfo —html file-name.texi` but on [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#Invoking-texi2any) they recommend `texi2any`. When I try `texi2any —html file-name.texi` I get "no such command error".

(I'm using emacs Texinfo Minor Mode.)

I copy my Texfinfo file below:

```
@title Sample Title
@page
@vskip 0pt plus 1filll
@insertcopying
@end titlepage
     
@c Output the table of the contents at the beginning.
@contents
     
@ifnottex
@node Top
@top GNU Sample
     
@insertcopying
@end ifnottex
     
@menu
* First Chapter::    The first chapter is the
                           only chapter in this sample.
* Second Chapter::
* Third Chapter::
* Index::            Complete index.
@end menu
     
     
@node First Chapter
@chapter First Chapter
     
@cindex chapter, first
     
This is the first chapter.
@cindex index entry, another
     
Here is a numbered list.
     
@enumerate
@item
This is the first item.
     
@item
This is the second item.
@end enumerate

@node Second Chapter
@chapter Second Chapter
     This is the second chapter

@node Third Chapter
@chapter Third Chapter
     This is the third chapter

@node Index
@unnumbered Index
     
@printindex cp
     
@bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't waste your time learning `TexInfo` ... instead rely on `org-mode` to create `texi` and `info` files.

FWIW, The Org manual itself is written in `org` and gets exported via `ox-texinfo` to `texi` and other formats like `info`, `html` and `pdf` files.

---

Do

```lisp
(require 'ox-texinfo)
```

and while visiting a `org` file, do `C-c C-e i o`.

If you take a look `Org mode`'s Makefile, you will get recipes for converting `texi` files to `html` and `pdf`.

1. https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/blob/4d8d7d6cb42e388572b4f5d227e9b3c9da6ca4a7/mk/default.mk#L173

[image: ox-texinfo]

Comment: That's great, thanks! Do you know if I can add to the org file Texinfo commands like `@smallbook`? And there were some errors added during conversion like it added `@documentencoding UTF-8` which gives an error.

Comment: Also menu items did not work well, I don't know how to handle that. Otherwise it looks great. So, I compose the whole book as one org file with Chapters as first headings, and subsections as secondary headings and then convert the file to `.texi`, right?

Comment: Why don't you update the question with a small `org` snippet that you want to convert in to a book.  It is better if you share it as a `gist` on `github` or as `pastebin` text.  It is easier to understand your problems, if you give me examples.  Post the `org` file, post the `errors` etc. and let me see if I can help you in anyway.

Comment: Ok. I added a test org file and resulting `.texi` file to github https://github.com/azeynel/texinfo It looks good but, one major issue is that it did not recognize the Latex equations. I think Texinfo only uses plain text `Tex`. Is there a way to make Texinfo recognize the Latex code?

Comment: I put the html here http://cavendish-deneyi.com/test/Introduction.html#Introduction

Comment: It would be nice to have the Contents on a separate page like this https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents but I don't know how this is done.

Comment: Support for math equations in `texinfo` is only couple of days old [PATCH Re: No mathematics in Texinfo exports](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2022-09/msg00382.html).   If you want the nodes to be NOT split then do,  `makeinfo --html --number-sections --number-sections --no-split --css-ref "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual.css"`.    I don't know how you setup file is ` ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org`.  Anyways,  looks like you have figured out most of the things.

Comment: I have Texinfo 6.8 installed, I exported again but still does not recognize the equations. Do I need to make any changes?

Comment: Are you running `org-mode` from git?  If `C-h v  org-texinfo-with-latex` doesn't report anything, you aren't running the very very latest org version.  If you know how to patch locally, apply this patch https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/commit/?id=c940b460c7bb31e98089286a5a45306cc27034cc.

Comment: If you are in a hurry, download https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs/org-mode.git/plain/lisp/ox-texinfo.el?id=c940b460c7bb31e98089286a5a45306cc27034cc.   Do `M-x load-file <downloaded-ox-texinfo.el>` and try exporting it again.  MAY BE MAY BE it works, if luck is on your side.

Comment: You referenced this: `makeinfo --html --number-sections --number-sections --no-split --css-ref "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual.css"` but it gave an error for `—css-ref`.  Instead I used `--css-include="file-path-to-css"` I didn't get an error with the command but it could not open the GNU css file. I tried my own css file, `--css-include="http://cavendish-deneyi.com/css/worg-classic-new.css"` it could not open that either. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how to patch locally. I thought of writing equations as text. http://cavendish-deneyi.com/test/Introduction.html#Introduction

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in creating `Table of Contents` ...

When in an `org` buffer do

`C-c C-e d #`

and make sure that the option `toc` has value `t`.

---

If you are interested in creating `index`-es look for `#+cindex`, `#+vindex` etc in the [`org-manual.org`](https://github.com/bzg/org-mode/tree/main/doc).

See also [Org Manual: Texinfo Export:  Indices](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Indices.html)

or

Copy the following snippet to your `*scratch*` buffer, go to the end of line and do `C-x C-e`.

```lisp
(info "(org) Indices")
```

---

Support for math equations in `texinfo` is only couple of days old [PATCH Re: No mathematics in Texinfo exports](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2022-09/msg00382.html).

---

If you want the nodes to be NOT split then do,

```
makeinfo --html --number-sections --number-sections --no-split --css-ref "https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual.css"`
```